# How to scroll to a specific UITableViewCell top to UITableView top when load view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to scroll  specific  table view cell to top when load view controller

this method is working fine. but when cell height changes dynamically cell doesn't scroll to the top instead it scroll to center

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "slideshowTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! slideshowTableViewCell

    if(self.scrollEnabled){

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.imageId, section: 0)
        self.slideshowView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)


        self.scrollEnabled = false
    }
```

Comment: Please stop calling scrollToRow on cellForRowAt method. It's very bad approach. You can calculate indexPath and call `scrollToRow` on viewWillAppear and make it called only one time.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `scrollToRow` on `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tblList.scrollToRow(at: Your_desired_indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
}
```